# MongoDB Aggregation - Buckets Boundaries to Referenced Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

To whom this may concern:

I would like to know if there is some workaround in MongoDB to set the "boundaries" field of a "$bucket" aggregation pipeline stage to an array that's already in the previous aggregation stage. (Or some other aggregation pipeline that will get me the same result). I am using this data to create a histogram of a bunch of values. Rather than retrieve 1 million-or-so values, I can receive 20 buckets with their respective counts.

The previous stages of yield the following result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa6fad883d3a9b8c6ad50a"), 
    "boundaries" : [ 73.0, 87.25, 101.5, 115.75, 130.0 ], 
    "value" : 83.58970621935025
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cfa6fe0883d3a9b8c6ad5a8"), 
    "boundaries" : [ 73.0, 87.25, 101.5, 115.75, 130.0 ], 
    "value" : 97.3261380262403
},
...
```

The "boundaries" field for every document is a result a facet/unwind/addfield with some statistical mathematics involving "value" fields in the pipeline. Therefore, every "boundaries" field value is an array of evenly spaced values in ascending order, all with the same length and values.

The following stage of the aggregation I am trying to perform is:

```
$bucket: {
    groupBy: "$value",
    boundaries : "$boundaries" ,
    default: "no_group",
    output: { count: { $sum: 1 } }
}
```

I get the following error from the explain when I try to run this aggregation:

```
{ 
    "ok" : 0.0, 
    "errmsg" : "The $bucket 'boundaries' field must be an array, but found type: string.", 
    "code" : NumberInt(40200), 
    "codeName" : "Location40200"
}
```

The result I would like to get is something like this, which is the result of a basic "$bucket" pipeline operator:

```
{
    "_id" : 73.0, // range of [73.0,87.25)
    "count" : 2 // number of documents with "value" in this range.
}, {
    "_id" : 87.25, // range of [87.25,101.5)
    "count" : 7 // number of documents with "value" in this range.
}, {
    "_id" : 101.5,
    "count" : 3
}, ...
```

What I know:

- The [JIRA documentation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23815) says

> 'boundaries' must be constant values (can't use "$x", but can use {$add: [4, 5]}), and must be sorted.

What I've tried:

- [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/) does not have a linear "granularity" setting. By default, it tries to evenly distribute the values amongst the buckets, and the bucket ranges are therefore spaced differently.
- Building the constant array by retrieving the pipeline results, and then adding the constant array into the pipeline again. This is effective but inefficient and not atomic, as it creates an O(2N) time complexity. I can live with this solution if needs be.

There HAS to be a solution to this. Any workaround or alternative solutions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: So for each `value` you want each `boundaries` value with a `count` of how many times that boundary appears? Or you just want an array of aggregated `boundaries` values with the count (across all `value`'s)? Your desired output is incomplete and could be misinterpreted.

Comment: Only trying to clarify, because something like this gives output similar to what you have as your desired output: `db.collection.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$boundaries" },{ $group: { _id: { value: '$value', boundaries: '$boundaries' }, 'count': { '$sum': 1 }}},{ $group: {_id: '$_id.boundaries', 'count': { '$sum':  1 }}}]).pretty()`

Comment: @MattOestreich: Apologies for the confusion in the desired output. I will update this to better reflect what I'm looking for. What I am trying to do is determine between which 2 numbers in the "boundaries" array the "value" falls between. For example in the first document in the example, the value 83.58970621935025 falls between 73 and 87.25. So the count of 73 increases by 1. The next example, 97.3261380262403, falls between 87.25 and 101.5, so 87.25 increases by 1. This is my understanding of how the "$bucket" pipeline operator works.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean. You want to use the boundaries array as the actual boundaries in the bucket pipeline

Comment: @MattOestreich Yes, exactly, except the "boundaries" field in the "$bucket" operator won't allow you to use a referenced array, namely the aforementioned boundaries array. Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: After digging into this a little bit, it looks like the 'boundaries' field must contain an array of ***constant*** values.. Meaning, any value used in that field will be interpreted literally. If you use `"$boundaries"` in that field, it will be interpreted as a string.  The boundaries you want to use are not constant values, right? Meaning, you can't just 'hard code' those values in the `boundaries` `$bucket` field?

Comment: @Matt -- The $boundaries array values are determined from a previous aggregation stage, even though they are the same for all documents, so it's not something I can hard-code without having to have MongoDB perform the query more than once.

Comment: Gotcha.. Would it be possible to update your question with your full query and some raw sample data (from the collection)? Obviously, you can use fake data... It's possible there is a better way to construct the overall query?

Comment: Also, is the size of your `"$boundaries"` array constant, or can that change depending upon the query?  Meaning, in your example, the `"$boundaries"` field has 5 elements in it - will there always be 5 elements?

Comment: @MattOestreich no, the size of the "$boundaries" array is not constant. It changes based on the query. From where I am right now I can't post the full query (it's also about 80-something lines of JSON so I don't think SO would take too kindly to that), but I can tell you that I have a value in my data structure that I $project first. I then do a $facet, with one of the pipelines containing a $group that allows me to get the maximum and minimum value of that field in all my documents. The other pipeline in "$facet" keeps the actual values of the field as an array, which leaves me with one...

Comment: ... document: with a field for the maximum and minimum, and with an array for all of the "values" from the field involved. I then use the maximum and minimum values from the group to create an evenly spaced array of $boundaries based on the number of bins I choose. I then unwind the "$values" array, so that I'm left with the "previous stages" result. I'm basically trying to get the interval-frequency values of a certain field my documents. Hopefully this makes sense.